# Display thumbnail image but print full_res using generateimage.php?url=

Tags: php

I have a page which will display photos. I want it to load the thumbnail version of the photo, but when I come to print it should display the highres version.

The photo's are loaded using PHP (imagecreatefromjpeg).

```
src=\"php/generateimage.php?imgname=".$_SESSION['ROOT_PATH']."data/images/".$value2['location']."&restraint=".$restraint."\"
```

I have found that by using "display:none" the generateimage.php is not creating the image for print. And when I come to print them, which changes the images to "display:block-inline" the images simply are not available.

Using "visibility:hidden" still loads the images into memory which slows the computer down which is why I don't really want to display them before printing.

I hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not open a new window, load the image, then initiate the print?

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-g-640-480-8.jpg"><br>
<button onclick="printImage();">Print</button>
<script>
function printImage() {
    var popup = window.open();
    var img = popup.document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-640-480-8.jpg";
    img.onload = function() {
        popup.print();
        popup.close();
    };
    popup.document.body.appendChild(img);
}
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LAsX/) (Instead of low quality and high quality, it's gray-scale and color)

Comment: There are multiple images that need a certain layout

Comment: Please post an example of multiple images with a specific layout. I believe this method can be applied to a set of images as well. Essentially, the preview page is shown as first, once the print button is pressed, JavaScript will generate the actual print page, and then attempt to print it. If the user has no intention to print it, your server saves bandwidth because the high-res images are never loaded.

Comment: I see what you mean actually, let me adapt you code and see if that will work for me.